# SSH interactive shell not identical to 'sh' sub-shell or non-interactive SSH shell

Tags: ssh, remote-control

### TL;DR

This works:

```
ssh me@1.2.3.4
$ qconfig
```

But these do *not* work (which makes no sense to me, as they should be the same):

```
ssh me@1.2.3.4 qconfig
sh: qconfig: cannot execute - No such file or directory
```

or

```
ssh me@1.2.3.4
$ sh
$ qconfig
sh: qconfig: cannot execute - No such file or directory
```

I want to use `ssh me@1.2.3.4 "some; commands; including; qconfig"`. How?

### Long Version

I have a command which I would like to submit to a remote host via a non-interactive ssh command or from sh sub-shell, but it is not found when submitted that way even though it *is* found during a normal, interactive session.

Details:

> OS: QNX
>
> Shell: sh
>
> Interactive command in which everything works as expected: `ssh
>   me@1.2.3.4` then supply `qconfig` at prompt
>
> though if I do `sh` then `qconfig` at this point, it does not work in that sub-shell
>
> Non-interactive command in which things do *not* work: `ssh me@1.2.3.4
>   qconfig`

Example:

```
[me.LOCAL-PC] > ssh me@1.2.3.4
me@1.2.3.4's password:
remotehost:/home/me $ echo $SHELL
/bin/sh
remotehost:/home/me $ qconfig
<…> (it works fine here)
remotehost:/home/me $ sh
remotehost:/home/me $ qconfig
sh: qconfig: cannot execute - No such file or directory
remotehost:/home/me $ exit
remotehost:/home/me $ sh -c qconfig
sh: qconfig: cannot execute - No such file or directory
remotehost:/home/me $ exit
[me.LOCAL-PC] > ssh me@1.2.3.4 qconfig
me@1.2.3.4's password:
sh: qconfig: cannot execute - No such file or directory
```

I'm not very familiar with QNX, so I wasn't sure if qconfig was a built-in or not. It would make sense that it is since qconfig is not on my PATH, and if I do `which qconfig` it says `which: no qconfig in /usr/bin:/bin:<…>`.

I have since seen that there is a QNX qconfig as seen at [this link](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino_utilities%2Fq%2Fqconfig.html), but I'm not so sure that's what is executing even when it does work for me since the one I am using does not accept the command line options listed at that page - I tried `-a`, `-b`, and `-c` and it said `-a: No such file or directory`.

What are the differences that could cause such a problem? More importantly, **how do I get the `ssh me@1.2.3.4 <command>` shell to correctly use the command the same as the `ssh me@1.2.3.4` shell does?**

Comment: So I figured out how to work around this specific command. Unfortunately, I now have similar problems with other commands as well which are no aliased, but the nuances are different and that would be a different question.

Answer (score 0):

And of course, after endless searching and hair-pulling I finally ask here on StackExchange, but then I finally figure it out just a half hour later.

**Check to see if your command is an alias.**

```
remotehost:/home/me $ alias
qconfig='some other command'
```

If it is an alias that is not getting set, then you could directly supply the command that your alias would do. So if `qconfig='some other command'`, then do `ssh me@1.2.3.4 some other command`

Apparently someone set up the system so that the command I am trying to run is aliased. I am used to working on machines where `which <command>` will tell you if the command is an alias, so I did not think to check that in this case.